# Why adding an SSL domain to WordPress Multisite causes: "Potential Security Risk Ahead" warning

Tags: wordpress, cpanel, wpmu

I have a WordPress MultiSite (WPMS) with several sites as sub folders.
Running with SSL on main domain all is OK.

In order to assign one of the child sites to an independent domain:

- I have set a new SSL for the domain.
- The new domain DNS points to the server.
- The domain was added on the server, pointing to the WPMS root folder.
- In WPMS network admin - the sub site is define as https://new-site.com

I was expecting the above to work, but I get the warning (Chrome, FF):

Warning: Potential Security Risk Ahead

What am I missing?? - Huge thanks!